# Query leads matching source_url and sort on lead_detail

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

`GravityForms` for WordPress is awesome. We are using it in a project but are running into something where we get stuck. GravityForms saves the "`source_url`" on submissions to determine where the submission came from. That's the basis of what we want: display submissions for page Y. We got that working using this query:

```
$responses = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_rg_lead WHERE source_url='".$source_url."'");
```

But now we want to sort and search on values the user have submitted when filling out the form. This data is saved in `wp_rg_lead_details` with the following structure:

```
|id|lead_id|form_id|field_number|value|
```

I want to sort on, and query a `LIKE` on the "value" of that table, matching a value from `wp_rg_lead` where `source_url = x`. But I'm stuck, I'm not sure how to set that up using joins or other MySQL functions.

It's important that the `LIKE` can extend to multiple values matching field_number `x`, `y` or `z` (in example).

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3352a/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you asking for, maybe this:

```
SELECT d.* FROM ( wp_rg_lead_details d
    JOIN wp_rg_lead l ON (d.lead_id = l.id))
 WHERE l.source_url = '$source_url' 
    AND d.value like '%$value%';
```

assuming there is a column `id` in your table `wp_rg_lead`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I maybe should have mentioned that I have to do a LIKE query on wp_rg_lead_details rows with i.e. field_number 1, 4 and 9 matching $value. I only want the results from wp_rg_lead where such a condition is positive. MY responses should be an row with al the fields from wp_rg_lead and wp_rg_lead_details. Would must be complex, considering wp_rg_lead_details can contain up to 20 references to the wp_rg_lead row I'm quering.

Comment: again im not sure what filter you want. `value` match for one of the specified `field_number` or `value` match for all the specified `field_number` or a third one `value` match for one `field_number` but the form must also have the others specified `field_number`